# Make a window on screen using window id

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to Mac API. I can get the list of window from the following function.

```
NSArray *windowInfos = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID);
```

Is it possible to make a window on screen if the window is not on screen. If so, How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Does the window you are trying to make visible belong to your application?  If so, you more likely to just want to do something like `[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]`, where `myWindow` is an `NSWindow*` outlet connected to a window in a nib file in your app.  Or does the window you are trying to make visible belong to a different application?  If so, it would seem rather strange to be trying to control the visibility of windows in a different app; perhaps in that case you could be more specific about what exactly you are trying to achieve, and perhaps there would be a better mechanism (distributed notifications, for example) to achieve it.

Comment: The window belongs to other application. Ex: Google Chrome, Finder etc.